# Lots of packages are missing in EPEL for RHEL7

Tags: installation, rpm, rhel7, epel

I am trying to install any GUI desktop on the RHEL7, what originally does not have any. 
There was even no ntfs-3g installed to work with NTFS file system.
really "nice" build is this RHEL7!!!! 
and i m using the EPEL - repos for that in :

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
while another the link to
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
 is not working.
So i installed the epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm with rpm. 
But i do not have the group '**Server with GUI**'in yum there, (what is recommended to install).
 trying install gnome-desktop, x windows system, xfce, whatever i get the message about **lots** of unsatisfied dependencies like:
lots with libgtk*
libX11*
gk* whatever
so i guess the dependencies for GNOME are missing.
Yeah, so many libs are not included in the RHEL7 from the beginning, bravo to this version.
I guess there is no info about the dependencies in the epel package or 
even in gnome-desktop-2.32.0-17.el7.x86_64.rpm.

Can someone  please tell where from download **all** (means **realy all**) 
dependencies for GNOME Desktop or any other desktop?

*before this issue i guessed, every package must have list of all dependencies to it , otherwise it is just... stupid*

Comment: This question is purely infrastructure related and so belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the EPEL repository for GUI on RHEL. All required packages, including all necessary dependencies, are a part of the default RHEL repositories.

Make sure that your installation is properly registered and subscribed (see [How to register and subscribe a system to the Red Hat Customer Portal using Red Hat Subscription-Manager](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273)).

Then you should be able to install a GUI environment of your choice without any outside dependencies, i.e. it should be possible to execute, for example:

```
# yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
```

See more detailed info at [How to install a graphical user interface (GUI) for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5238).